# Fabric with Unity iOS - unable to configure app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

I installed Fabric and Crashlytics without any problems last week, and when launching my iOS app via XCode I can see the setup messages

```
Fabric.Internal.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsInit:RegisterExceptionHandlers()
Fabric.Internal.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsInit:Awake()
```

in the output log, but my app isn't being registered by Fabric. If I log in to their site I am directed to https://www.fabric.io/onboard/pending, and can't seem to continue past "(1) Add the first SDK to your project". Is there a step I have perhaps missed, or a library I need to manually add?

I also tried throwing a [non fatal exception](https://docs.fabric.io/unity/crashlytics/test-crash.html) after my app had launched, my understanding being that this should just throw an exception, but my app crashes and closes, with the following error being thrown in XCode. Is this normal?

```
NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.
  at Fabric.Crashlytics.Internal.Impl.Log (System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at StartMenuController.OnClickParentModeBtn () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ButtonAnimator+<InvokeEvent>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: I don't think the tag [[tag:fabric]] is appropriate. The tag description refers to a python library, not whatever service you're using. That said, I can't rule it out.

Comment: It seems the tag is being used for both now, quite a few other users are using it for the Fabric analytics service. If there is a better tag I'll be happy to change it.

Comment: Usually in such cases it's best to make a new tag and retag the old questions (tag ambiguity is terrible). I don't know what to call it though. Taking an example off Meta, [poisson] got split into [poisson-distribution] and [poisson-equation] (or at least, that was the suggestion).

Comment: I totally agree! Following the official stack overflow URL over at fabric.io the best tag seems to be [google-fabric]. Thanks for picking up on this.

Comment: Already a tag for it, awesome.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Just to confirm, you added Fabric into the first scene of your app?

Comment: Hey Mike, yep both objects are present, and judging by the output in XCode it looks like they're being called.